# How to prompt an error message when user inputs invalid argument to the public getter function

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays

I'm new to solidity and smart contract programming. I'm currently using the online remix IDE to run my program. I want to display a error message when the user tries to ask for the value of an array element that does not exist.

This is my array

`offer[] public asks;`

If my understanding is correct the above line automatically generates a getter function, the user inputs the array index value 'i' and the function returns `asks[i]`, how do I prompt a error message saying 'array index exceeded' when the user inputs invalid index value?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example.

You probably want to use mapping for this.

```
contract Validator {

// record of valid ids  
mapping(uint => bool) isValidId;  // make it public for a getter

// function to return valid for understanding only since we have a getter.

// this is the same ad calling isValidId(id) if public
function isvalid(uint256 id) public returns(bool) {

    return isValidId[id];
}
 
  // set the state of an id to true
  function setValid(uint256 id) public onlyOwner {

    isValidId[id] = true;
}


function thatRequireValidId(uint256 id){
 require(isValidId[id], "Not a valid ID");
}

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using arrays? I would like to know the length of the array at a later part of my program.